# Which nth is this child?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom, sass

nth-child is a pretty handy pseudo element selector to target the child I want to style with CSS. Unfortunately, I have a terrible time when trying to decide which number (nth) is the child that I want to target in the DOM.

So I was thinking is there a way to use a JavaScript/ JQuery function that would give me the exact number of the child in the DOM?

Also, if there is a SCSS (sass) function that could do that, I would love to have some insights.

The following code might demonstrate exactly what I want :

```
<section>
 <p>Little</p>
 <p>Piggy</p>    <!-- Want this one -->
 <p>foo</p>
 <p>bar</p>
 <p>String</p>
 <p>String</p>
 <p>String</p>
 <p>String</p>
 <p>String</p>
 <p>String</p>
 <p>String</p>
 <p>String</p>
 <p>String</p>
 <p>String</p>
</section>
```

this DOM is simple, I can target the second p child`p:nth-child(?) { color: red; }`. Only thing my DOM is not that simple; it has tons and tons of p, that I do not know which child number is it.

Comment: What is your goal? If you had JavaScript code that could give you the `nth-child()` string for a particular DOM element, what would you do with it? Since you'd already have a reference to the DOM element by the time you called that function, it's not clear what the point would be of getting that selector.

Comment: So you use a selector that targets the parent you want.... than you use the nth child.

Comment: Also note that `nth-child()` is about elements and their siblings; that is, elements with a common parent. If you're targetting just one element, then you simply count (starting from 1) the elements that come before it.

Comment: How do you know which one you want to select? and what is your reason to select it?
In other words, what makes this `<p>` different than any other `<p>`?
your answer is crucial. 

if you have, say, 50 `<p>`s inside of some `<div>` and you're trying to select the 33rd one using `nth-child()` than you should probably give this `<p>` a different `class` or `id`.

Comment: You want to get index, but when? onclick on the element or any other events?

Comment: @Azim Does not matter the goal is to get the index number (nth) of the element I want to target.

Comment: If you have `n` then why not use jQuery [`eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) method? @AndrewMk

Comment: @Azim I have my own methodology when it comes to segregating behavior (JavaScript) and styles (CSS). Just to keep things clean and organized,I try to avoid --as much as I can-- mixing my styles with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using [`Array#find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) we find the target element from a group of elements using a predicate. Then we can find the element's siblings via the common parent using @Oriol's method. Now we can get the index of the target from the siblings using [`Array#indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf), and add 1 since [nth child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) is 1 based (the 1st element index is 1), and the `Array#indexOf()` method is 0 based.

```
function findNth(baseSelector, predicate) {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll(baseSelector); // find all elements in the page that fit the selector

  var target = [].slice.call(elements, 0).find(predicate); // find the target by using the predicate

  if(!target) { // target not found
    return -1;
  }

  var siblings = target.parentNode.children; // find the target's siblings

  return [].slice.call(siblings, 0).indexOf(target) + 1; // return the target's nth index
}
```

```js
function findNth(baseSelector, predicate) {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll(baseSelector); // find all elements in the page that fit the selector
  
  var target = [].slice.call(elements, 0).find(predicate); // find the target by using the predicate
  
  if(!target) { // target not found
    return -1;
  }
  
  var siblings = target.parentNode.children; // find the target's siblings
  
  return [].slice.call(siblings, 0).indexOf(target) + 1; // return the target's nth index
}

function predicate(element) {
  return element.textContent === 'Piggy';
}

var piggyIndex = findNth('p', predicate);

console.log('The index is:', piggyIndex);
```

```html
<section>
 <p>Little</p>
 <p>foo</p>
 <p>bar</p>
</section>

<section>
 <p>Little</p>
 <p>Piggy</p>    <!-- Want this one -->
 <p>foo</p>
 <p>bar</p>
</section>
```

Comment: Can I use this without adding a class selector to the element I want to target its nth number?

Comment: That's perfect, I will accept this as the answer, but only after one thing; if you can provide a SCSS way of doing this (if possible). if it is not possible with SCSS, just mention that in your answer.

Comment: @Oriol 's answer adds an id to the element.I do not require that. I just have a comment: the triple equal should compare for full equality between the two texts inside. Suppose I have a lengthy text paragraph inside and I want just to compare for a word or couple of words that exist to target the element, what the code would be?

Comment: @AndrewMk My answer does not require an ID, only requires a reference to the element, which can be obtained in a great variety of ways. This answer returns the index among all paragraphs in the document, so it can't be used in `:nth-child`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) on the parent's [`children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children) collection:

```
[].indexOf.call(child.parentElement.children, child) + 1;
```

```js
function getIndex(child) {
  return [].indexOf.call(child.parentElement.children, child) + 1;
}
function getSelector(element) {
  var arr = [];
  while(element.parentElement) {
    arr.push(':nth-child(' + getIndex(element) + ')');
    element = element.parentElement;
  }
  if (element !== document.documentElement) return false;
  return ':root > ' + arr.reverse().join(' > ');
}
var el = document.getElementById('i-want-this-one');
console.log('Index: ' + getIndex(el));
document.styleSheets[0].insertRule(getSelector(el) + ' { color: red; }', 0);
```

```html
<section>
 <p>Little</p>
 <p id="i-want-this-one">Piggy</p>
 <p>foo</p>
 <p>bar</p>
 <p>String</p>
 <p>String</p>
 <p>String</p>
 <p>String</p>
 <p>String</p>
 <p>String</p>
 <p>String</p>
 <p>String</p>
 <p>String</p>
 <p>String</p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

A way to remedy the potential to target the wrong child is to identify the section first, and then simply count to the required child:

```html
    <style>
    #market p:nth-child(2) {color:#f00}
    </style>
    
    <section id="wall">
    <p>Humpty</p>
    <p>Dumpty</p>
    <p>King's horses</p>
    <p>King's men</p>
    <p>foo</p>
    <p>bar</p>
    <p>String</p>
    <p>String</p>
    <p>String</p>
    </section>

    <section id="market">
    <p>Little</p>
    <p>Piggy</p>    <!-- Want this one -->
    <p>foo</p>
    <p>bar</p>
    <p>String</p>
    <p>String</p>
    <p>String</p>
    <p>String</p>
    <p>String</p>
    <p>String</p>
    <p>String</p>
    <p>String</p>
    <p>String</p>
    <p>String</p>
    </section>
```